# Webfont loader with Google Fonts is not using https

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

I am using webfont loader for fonts on my site, and have the following setup:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js" integrity="sha384-pvXSwSU09c+q9mPyY++ygUHWIYRoaxgnJ/JC5wcOzMb/NVVu+IDniiB9qWp3ZNWM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**JS**

```
WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Libre Franklin']
  }
});
```

And then in my `.htaccess` I am setting sources for stylesheets as part of my Content Security Policy like so:

```
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
```

But when the site loads the font it is using the `http://` source for the font, so it is being blocked by the CSP and I am getting this error message in the console:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com".
```

**How can I make sure the site is loading the https:// version of the stylesheet?**

Answer (score 0):

the library `webfonts.js` uses `location.protocol` to adjust the request `http` or `https` when your project is in domain under `https` it will be changed to https